# Phing + PHPDocumentor: BuildException: Error including PhpDocumentor setup class file "Setup.inc.php"

Tags: php, pear, phpdoc, phing

```
Phing Version: 2.6.1
PHP Documentor Version: 2.2.0
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.4.17
```

When I run my build file everything runs smoothly until the phpdoc execution which throws a BuildException: Error including PhpDocumentor setup class file. The error is encountered when phing tries to include "phpDocumentor/Setup.inc.php". The pear include path is present but Setup.inc.php doesn't exist anywhere, even in the latest PHPDoc repository. Is this something I should create? I can't find documentation anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phing's "[PhpDocumentorTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs51.html)" taskexpects phpDocumentor 1.x.  Since you have 2.x, you need to use the "[DocBloxTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs52.html)" task.  The latter is still named after DocBlox since it was integrated into Phing before DocBlox merged with phpDocumentor to form phpDocumentor 2.x.

Comment: Thanks, using the example in the DocBloxTask link above worked perfectly.